# Backbone.js Collection does not fetch data from api

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm pretty new to Backbone.js and I have some problems with fetching data from my api.
I do the following:

```
var pc = new PostCollection();
pc.fetch();
```

When I look in my browser I can see the request to the spcecified url in my collection and the response also contains the data I expect. But my collection always stays empty.
So i tried to add the parse method to my collection. But this method is never executed.
What am I doing wrong?

My Collection:

```
var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Post,
  url: '/fpress/api.php',
  latest: function() {
    return this.filter(function(game) {
      return post.get('id') > 1;
    })
  },
  parse: function(resp) {
    alert(resp);
  }
});
```

Comment: What does the server's response look like?

Comment: Agree with Edward, sounds like your server is not executing the request properly.

Comment: He did say that the response contains the data he expects, right?

Comment: @skelle i had the exact same problem and clearing the browsers cache did the trick. I did also verify that the json is correctly formed otherwise the parse method does not execute(even thought the doc says it does)

Comment: forgive me for making a statement i didn't check, but isn't it normal that your collection is empty, when you override the parse method with nothing more than an alert in it?

Comment: @Sander is right, but I think there is still something else as he said that the parse method never executes.  @skelle -- I think you're doing it right so maybe there is something else in play.  I assume you haven't overridden Backbone.sync? or can you try adding an `error` callback to your `pc.fetch()`

Comment: @Deeptechtons so the json data MUST fit the backbone expections otherwise the parse method is not executed? my JSON response looks like: `[
     {title: "first title", text: "first text", id: 1},
     {title: "sec title", text: "sec text", id: 2},
     {title: "third title", text: "third text", id: 3}
  ]` 
Is this ok or malformed?
@timDunham I added `pc.bind("error", function(model, error) {
        alert(error);
      })`but I only get object object in my alert and when I inspect the object I can see Code 200, my response and so on but no error information

Answer (score 0):

Your parse method needs to return something, so if you `return resp;` in your parse method it will be filled with the same data as your alert.

Comment: as I said before the parse method gets NEVER executed. I event don't see the alert with my server response

Comment: you could try `var pc = new PostCollection;` instead of `var pc = new PostCollection();`

Comment: I'm stille not seeing the alert form the parse method :/

Comment: Then it seems like there's something else going on elsewhere in you code that's not included here.  If you're seeing your response in in your browser net call and all the data that is supposed to comeback is there, then your service is working and the problem lies somewhere in your backbone code.  If you can post more of your code, or a link if this stuff is out somewhere I'm sure someone will be able to solve the issue.  Otherwise, trial and error usually works :)

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any solution or workaround about this one? thank you.

Comment: are you making a cross domain request? or is the url in your model pointing to somewhere on your server?

Comment: this is the link of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817317/backbone-persistence-retrieve-the-data-from-the-server-but-doesnt-fill-collecti

Answer (score 0):

The parse method isn't available in older versions of backbone.js such as 0.5.3 - what version are you using?