# backbone persistence retrieve the data from the server but doesn't fill collection and models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm starting with Backbone. I'm new to this and I'm still somewhat confused.

I have this code:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Item,
url: 'http://localhost/InterprisePOS/Product/loaditembycategory/Event Materials',
});

var items = new Items();
var onSuccess = function(result){ alert("success"); };

items.fetch({ success: onSuccess });
```

When I look at Firebug the response is somehow correct. It returns the right data. But when I dig much deeper items is empty. I don't even know how to display the data from the server using Backbone. Any help? Thanks

## update

i have managed this to somehow work.

```
from:
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend();
to:
var Item = Backbone.Model;
```

I can see the collection being populated but with only one item. Though i still can get it to alert the result.

## another update

i managed to correct my success callback. My question now is how can i print the item model only?

Comment: also tried that. i added a alert on error callback but it wont fire either success or error.

Comment: i updated the code and added success and error callback.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably due to the full url, `http://...`.  when that goes to the jQuery ajax call it will see that, assume it's an external url and treat it as a cross-domain request.  Your success, error, and probably parse functions don't run because of that.

Also, you have a comma at the end of your url after the last quote.  if you're running this in IE you'll probably get a javascript error because of that.

Try using your url as a relative url.  Also, make sure you are running the application under your local web server, and not just opening the index.html file in your browser.

Comment: i managed the success and error callback to run. i had the structure wrong before. i corrected it somehow. There is no problem with regards on the url because i already created a app using jquery ajax i'm just want to use backbone to compare and contrast. So the CORS is not a factor anymore because i've dealt with it before. I would just like to print the Item model to test its power.

Comment: To print the model you need to pass it into a view and render the view, putting the rendered el into your dom

Comment: Can't i just print a test like putting it on alert? i'm in the process of learning backbone i just would like to see how everything works. step by step.

Comment: the collection or model you get back will be an object so if you alert that it will just say [object object]. Instead, do console.log and use firebug or the chrome developer tools to inspect the object.